Oracle SQL: most efficient way (in terms of network roundtrips) to do random little and scattered writes to a LOB column
I have a table with a BLOB column. Each BLOB can be up to 1GB in size. Updates of existing persistent BLOBs usually consist of thousands (~10k) of write microchunks at random offsets of around 100 bytes each, and so the probability of these writes being contiguous is very low.
We have to device a way grouping all of our writes and send them to Oracle in a way that is efficient for both the server (I/O) and client (amount of network-roundtrips). I think it can be done with OCILobWrite2 but I'm not sure how:

I don't understand the different and/or relation between polling and streaming mode.
I don't know the relation between polling/streaming and the amount of network roundtrips. Will the "network roundtrip" itself start when the last piece is written, and all the previous writes will be accumulated in memory somehow by OCI?
I don't know if OCI will smartly "group" writes that are contiguous or if I have to do it by myself.
The doc claims that it's better to group writes that are CHUNKSIZE-aligned, but:

If I'm using the polling and/or streaming mode, do I need to take care of that as well?
SecureFiles uses dynamically-sized chunks (as far as I understand), and so CHUNKSIZE is provided just for backward-compatibility. Is that advice of doing chunk-aligned writes a "deprecated advice" for SecureFile but no one from Oracle has remembered to fix the advice in the docs?
Anyway, if only 100 bytes have actually changed in a chunk of 16KiB, do I need to worry about doing chunk-aligned writes anyway?



NOTE: I'm aware OCI have a buffering mode for LOBs, but it's deprecated/unmaintained.

Tiny 100-byte changes are going to be problematic for several reasons, not just for network chattiness, but also   if chunks are the minimum LOB I/O size, assuming you have an 8K block size and therefore a chunk size of at least 8K (securefile still won't go below your block size), you would be doing far more I/O than you need each time. LOBs were not meant to be updated in this frequent, few-bytes-at-a-time way. It sounds to me like a redesign is needed.

Can you represent your data instead as a child table (or even nested table) of RAW(100) so you can do normal row updates, which would be cached and dirty buffers written lazily/asynchronously by DBWR like normal table data, and also require reduced network trips for the update? If 100 byte sections have independent meaning such that there's a business need to update at that granularity, perhaps your datatype should be aligned with that granularity rather than be a composite (LOB) that you have to work with surgically and inefficiently.

Securefile LOBs do have some performance enhancements over the old basicfile LOBs, principally the Write Gather Cache (WGC) which buffers writes and flushes periodically to reduce write I/O to disk. So it is not nearly as bad as writing one chunk (a multiple of your block size) for every write operation, even though the chunk remains the basic unit of I/O to disk for LOB segments.
I did some experimenting comparing 10,000 random 100 byte writes (1MB total) to a 16MB BLOB, with 10,000 random row updates to a RAW(100) column to compare the performance between using a BLOB and using a child table of RAW(100).
LOB setup:
 drop table lobtest;
 create table lobtest (myblob blob);

/*
** Initial population
*/
DECLARE
  var_myblob blob;
  var_mybuffer raw(100) := HEXTORAW('7785069247a730153313c7c8244db9228b0ce07a2aa8646cf1bc908bc7a275913c16a0081594f1b3979a515b7c37b61993e17caaccbe1401bd52ca34bf21d7a99b0c8220eae182a0f7ec71db249da8d96a585cf8fa81af6d09129d82afaafd7d60d77e4c');
  var_offset pls_integer;
  var_lob_size integer;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO lobtest VALUES (EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING myblob INTO var_myblob;
  
  FOR i IN 1..100000
  LOOP
    var_offset := ((i-1)*100)+1;
    dbms_lob.write(var_myblob,100,var_offset,var_mybuffer);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
/*
** Show LOB segment size
*/
SELECT ROUND(s.bytes/(1024*1024)) blob_mb,l.*
  FROM user_lobs l,
       user_segments s
 WHERE l.column_name = 'MYBLOB'
   AND l.segment_name = s.segment_name;  
/     

Result: 16MB
LOB update test
/*
** Capture session stats before
*/
drop table stat$before;
create table stat$before as 
SELECT sn.name,ss.value
  FROM v$mystat ss,
       v$statname sn
 WHERE ss.statistic# = sn.statistic#       
   AND (sn.name IN ('physical writes direct (lob)',
                   'physical write bytes',
                   'physical read bytes',
                   'physical write total bytes',
                   'redo size',
                   'undo change vector size')
        OR sn.name LIKE 'securefile%')                   
 ORDER BY ss.value DESC               
 /
/*
** Do 10,000 random writes to the BLOB created above in a single transaction
*/
DECLARE
  var_myblob blob;
  var_mybuffer raw(100) := HEXTORAW('7785069247a730153313c7c8244db9228b0ce07a2aa8646cf1bc908bc7a275913c16a0081594f1b3979a515b7c37b61993e17caaccbe1401bd52ca34bf21d7a99b0c8220eae182a0f7ec71db249da8d96a585cf8fa81af6d09129d82afaafd7d60d77e4c');
  var_offset pls_integer;
  var_lob_size integer;
  var_start_ts timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
  var_start_ts := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  
  SELECT myblob INTO var_myblob FROM lobtest WHERE ROWNUM = 1 FOR UPDATE;
    
  FOR i IN 1..10000
  LOOP
    var_offset := LEAST(FLOOR(ABS(dbms_random.random())/10000)*100,16000000)+1;
    dbms_lob.write(var_myblob,100,var_offset,var_mybuffer);
  END LOOP;
  
  COMMIT;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(SYSTIMESTAMP - var_start_ts);
END;
/

/*
** Capture session stats after and calculate diffs
*/
SELECT sn.name,ss.value - NVL(b.value,0) diff
  FROM v$mystat ss,
       v$statname sn,
       stat$before b
 WHERE ss.statistic# = sn.statistic#       
   AND (sn.name IN ('physical writes direct (lob)',
                   'physical write bytes',
                   'physical read bytes',
                   'physical write total bytes',
                   'redo size',
                   'undo change vector size')
        OR sn.name LIKE 'securefile%')  
   AND sn.name = b.name(+)
 ORDER BY diff DESC
 /

Result:

This was after running the above update test multiple times. Each time I ran it, the numbers dropped, showing the effect of the Write Gather Cache. These numbers show where they bottomed out, at their most efficient. The test did 1MB of updates (securefile bytes non-transformed = 1000000) using 10,000 separate write operations (securefile number of non-transformed flushes = 10000). It read 15MB (physical read bytes), generated 10MB of redo to the log (redo size), and 4MB of undo (undo change vector size). The Write Gather Cache was flushed 3,565 times (securefile number of flushes), or about 1 out of every 3 writes. The counters for physical write bytes/physical write total bytes appear to not be instrumented properly - 8192 is exactly one block/chunk in my case and there's no way it only wrote 1 block when it did 3,565 flushes. It appears the Write Gather Cache masks the real amount of disk write happening. If we assume each flush is a chunk, then we might suspect a total I/O of 29MB (3565 * 8192). v$segstat gives the figure 894 physical write operations (894 * 8192 = 7MB). Either way, we're doing a lot more than 1MB of writes, but the caching has prevented us from having to write 81MB like we would (presumably) with basicfile (10000 * 8192). Total time for the test: 3.3 seconds.
RAW(100) setup
 drop table lobtest2;
 create table lobtest2 (offset integer, blob_data raw(100));
 
 
DECLARE
  var_mybuffer raw(100) := HEXTORAW('7785069247a730153313c7c8244db9228b0ce07a2aa8646cf1bc908bc7a275913c16a0081594f1b3979a515b7c37b61993e17caaccbe1401bd52ca34bf21d7a99b0c8220eae182a0f7ec71db249da8d96a585cf8fa81af6d09129d82afaafd7d60d77e4c');
  var_offset pls_integer;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..100000
  LOOP
    var_offset := ((i-1)*100)+1;
    INSERT INTO lobtest2 VALUES (var_offset,var_mybuffer);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/ 
create index i_lobtest2 on lobtest2(offset);
/

RAW(100) update test
drop table stat$before;
create table stat$before as 
SELECT sn.name,ss.value
  FROM v$mystat ss,
       v$statname sn
 WHERE ss.statistic# = sn.statistic#       
   AND (sn.name IN ('physical writes direct (lob)',
                   'physical write bytes',
                   'physical read bytes',
                   'physical write total bytes',
                   'redo size',
                   'undo change vector size'))                   
 ORDER BY ss.value DESC               
 /
  
DECLARE
  var_mybuffer raw(100) := HEXTORAW('7785069247a730153313c7c8244db9228b0ce07a2aa8646cf1bc908bc7a275913c16a0081594f1b3979a515b7c37b61993e17caaccbe1401bd52ca34bf21d7a99b0c8220eae182a0f7ec71db249da8d96a585cf8fa81af6d09129d82afaafd7d60d77e4c');
  var_offset pls_integer;
  var_start_ts timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
  var_start_ts := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  
  FOR rec_offset IN (SELECT offset FROM lobtest2 ORDER BY REVERSE(TO_CHAR(offset)) FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY)
  LOOP
    UPDATE lobtest2 SET blob_data = var_mybuffer WHERE offset = rec_offset.offset;
  END LOOP;
  
  COMMIT;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(SYSTIMESTAMP - var_start_ts);  
END;
/ 
SELECT sn.name,ss.value - NVL(b.value,0) diff
  FROM v$mystat ss,
       v$statname sn,
       stat$before b
 WHERE ss.statistic# = sn.statistic#       
   AND (sn.name IN ('physical writes direct (lob)',
                   'physical write bytes',
                   'physical read bytes',
                   'physical write total bytes',
                   'redo size',
                   'undo change vector size'))  
   AND sn.name = b.name(+)
 ORDER BY diff DESC
 /

Result:

We still did 1MB of updates involving 10000 random 100-byte changes, the same as the previous test. The physical read/write metrics are meaningless because these were buffered reads/writes through the cache like normal table operations are. The foreground process doesn't have to do any of its own writes (other than to the redo log), as DBWR will perform that task later when it pleases. Total redo size was 3MB, undo size was 1MB, total time for the test: 0.18 secs.
Comparing the two tests, we can see that writing to the BLOB must read in the BLOB from disk (non-cached. You can change this with the CACHE setting but a 1GB BLOB is much too big to be cached), so there's a lot of physical direct path read that isn't needed in the RAW(100) scenario, which does no reads at all once everything is in the buffer cache. The BLOB method generated three times as much redo, four times as much undo, and performed an unquantifiable amount of writes (somewhere between 7x and 20x the actual amount of logical change). Just from a pure timing perspective, the RAW(100) method performed 17x faster than the BLOB method.
So while securefile LOBs have some good performance improvements over the basicfile,  they still can't compare with using conventional in-row datatypes. If you need the speed, the concurrency and locking mechanisms of normal row operations, the full benefit of caching, you're better off with a non-LOB approach such as the RAW(100) method suggested. You can write a PL/SQL function to reassemble the rows in the correct order and return a temporary BLOB if your consuming program needs it in that format.
Obviously this does not address network latency, which you can only reduce by buffering on the client-side so less changes are submitted to the database. But even then, fewer network round-trips are required with an UPDATE of a conventional in-row datatype than anything involving a LOB, since LOB operations require multiple operations per row (create or fetch the locator, open the lob, write, close, etc..). So getting away from a BLOB will also help with your concern about network latency.

Very interesting analysis. Still thinking about it. One thing, in the randomly generated offset (LOB case), did you mean abs(dbms_random.random()) % 10000 ? Because you got the quotient instead of the remained, which means you are probably doing all the writes at the end of the LOB. That's probably why the physical write bytes shows 8k (the last chunk).

@Abu, no, I tested that function out and got it working like I wanted - some random number at a 100 byte boundary but less than 16MB. I'm sure there is a better way but it was pretty random.

Ok you kinda convinced me. However, having a table of 1GiB/100 = 10 million rows scares a bit out of me, and I also have to test out the load times of 10 million rows for our initial blob read: we load the entire blob to memory in a in-memory file and we never unmap it. Our plan is that microwrites write both to memory and blob (with client side buffering or whatever), so we never read from the blob besides at the beginning (when our systems are turned on). Currently, reading the BLOB takes just 3s and it's fast enough since we pay that price only once. 10 million rows is crazy however.

@ABu, it's all relative. 10m is nothing in many environments. If you do test row insertions, be sure to use bulk array binds so you don't need a separate exec on that insert for each 100 byte piece.

Is there a way to iterate or see stats about the chunks of a LOB? I'm curious to know what is the actual chunk average size of my LOB to understand why, if the write gather cache is of 4MB, and is flushed when it's full, why with just 3 reads a flush happens. 3 writes (= 3 blocks of 16KiB each, which is the "illustrative" block size), forces a flush already. Flushes should happen each 256 writes, theoretically. If that's not the case, it means that SecureFiles is using blocks in the order of MBs.

@ABu, these session stats are a bit of voodoo, you they tend to elude attempts to exactly predict and explain. Oracle hasn't exactly instrumented every single thing as you'd expect, so sometimes we can be interpreting numbers wrongly. Check out dbms_lob.getchunksize, or you can read the whole thing through and check the session stat securefile allocation chunks. You should also run your own tests to compare the methods using assumptions more exactly matching your use case; see what holds the most promise.

I've done a stronger test for the RAW case, more similar to my actual case. Differences: I insert 1867776 different rows (just because, long history), and use as offset the "chunk index" instead, so the loop goes from i = 1 to 1867776, and the inserts are INSERT INTO lobtest2 VALUES (i, var_mybuffer);. I create the index, and then the update test goes from i = 1 to 10000, and the offset is choosen as: var_offset := 1 + mod(ABS(dbms_random.random()), 1867776);. The execution time is not on the order of milliseconds anymore, but takes around 5 and 10 seconds.

The other stats are very similar to yours, so I think you are seeying cache effects I'm not seeying because my offset are very much appart. In your shorter case, my stats are like yours, also in terms of time, but maybe because there's much more "stuff" in the cache since your writes are much more localized (closed in space)?

@ABu, make sure those updates are using the index and you aren't committing every piece individually. 10 seconds is far too long for 10,000 simple updates.

I'm positive. If I change the amount of rows from 1 million to 100k (10 times shorter), the time drops from 10 seconds to < 0.5s (10 times faster), which means the time is being proportional to the size of the table and not the number of updates, which is fixed (10k). I have done an explain plan of the query (for the 1 million case), and the plan says it's doing a index range scan, so the index is correct.

@ABu, if the time is proportional to the size of the table, then you aren't using the index. Index access for a fixed # of rows would be the same time no matter how big the table. The query plan you get when you manually explain the query and what the program is getting may not be the same. Can you share your update SQL, table/index DDL and execution plan?

I'm not able to reproduce the problem anymore, but it was clear, I changed the size and regenerated the table, and I saw the change in execution size, but now it's gone... maybe the database had congestion problems...

The solution was finally, instead of replacing the blob with millions of chunks, we have decided to keep the blob in a table, but, inspired by your idea, we replace all the writes by insertions into a child table, as if it were a write-buffer. An oracle job that runs once or twice a day merges all the chunks back into the blob using the dbms_lob package (and clear the child table). "Downloading" the file is now downloading the blob AND all the modified chunks. Thank for your idea of using a child table, it has been brilliant.
